# Passing one or more files in function in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, function

[image]

Here I have written a sample bash script, the problem with this is that I am able to successfully pass file to function remFun but I am unable to pass the file unique.txt to function printfile. In order to do that what I have to do please suggest.

The thing I am doing here is scanning for a particular file (input by user) then wanna eliminate repeated lines and write unique lines in another file then using another function print that file.

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use pictures of text, put the text verbatim in your question (between `\`\`\`` code blocks `\`\`\``)

Comment: AFAICT, you just want to do `sort -u -- *.txt > newfile`, why the extra complications with all those (poorly written as there are  many bad coding practices in there) functions?

Comment: `$1` is bad, `in *` is bad, comparisons are bad. Given a file with spaces or special characters in its name it will blow in your face. Please use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You’re setting the `resfile` variable and calling printFile with a different variable, `resFile`. Is this just a typo? Maybe you want `resFile=unique.txt`

Comment: @Mark Plotnick its just a typo my bad